# Getting "site cannot be reached" after adding custom domain

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I am trying to host my site using Firebase hosting. I have created a project and verified my domain by adding the TXT record. After this while connecting my domain after adding "A records", I am getting below error:

```
This site can’t be reached

www.shanmugavel.xyz refused to connect.
```

[image: My DNS configuration]

[image: Firebase configuration]
Please let me know, if I am missing anything.

Comment: It takes some time for the DNS to refresh and make changes to the records.

Comment: Thanks a Lot @JoelFernandes . My site works after 1 day.